# Show labels per serie in Highstock.js as in Highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm planning to use Highstocks.js after having used Highcharts in some other projects and I've noticed that the labels when moving the mouse over a series are not the same as in Highcharts.js making it more difficult to be read.

[image]
[image]

Instead of showing only the information of the selected series, it shows the information of all of them in the same label. 
This might be a bit confusing when there's multiple series as you have to pay attention to the color to identify the series name.

It doesn't even highlight the series you are currently over or anything to simplify the viewing to the final user.

---

You can see what I'm talking about with this two examples:

- [Highcharts.js](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/) (How I would like it)
- [Highstocks.js](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare) (How it actually is)

---

I'm wondering if there's anything which can be done to emulate that behavior. I've been taking a look at the [series options](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series) but I didn't find anything similar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can, it is very easy, just add:

```
shared: false
```

for tooltip options object on chart initialization.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5RGaC/

Comment: :) Thanks! It was quite simple haha :D

Comment: that's what i like about Highcharts - almost everything can be configured:)